# Gradle doesn't pick up Cucumber-jvm

Tags: cucumber, gradle, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I am trying to run Cucumber-jvm from Gradle. However no matter what I do I cannot get the features to actually run. They are always skipped while other JUnit tests are run. My features are in `src/test/resources` and I have a JUnit test in `src/test/java` with `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` and `@Feature(Myfeature.feature)` attributes specified. Here is my Gradle script:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '1.0.0.RC13'
    testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '1.0.0.RC13'
    testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-picocontainer', version: '1.0.0.RC13'
    testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-core', version: '1.0.0.RC13'
    testCompile group: 'org.picocontainer', name: 'picocontainer', version: '2.10.2'
}
```

If someone has an idea of what to do to fix this it would be appreciated. Cucumber-jvm documentation is non-existent.

Comment: So it appears that this particular issue was with cucumber RC13. I updated to RC15 and now I get an exception that Cucumber cannot find my features.`cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No features found at [Testfeature.feature]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got this working. Should be good for everyone to understand how to use Gradle and Cucumber-jvm together. First you need RC15 to start, other builds have issues that I don't quite understand. Your testcompile section needs to look like what I have above.

Next create a test in the `src/test/java/path/of/package/`. I haven't tested with other languages.The test needs use the JUnit `@RunWith` and Cucumber-Jvm's `@Feature(value="featurefile.feature")` attributes.

Put your .feature file in the root of `src/test/resources`. For some reason Cucumber doesn't pick up files in child folders.

Hope that saves people a lot of time.

Comment: If you want to put the feature file in a subdirectory, just change the @Feature attribute to match the path starting below the resources folder. So if it is src/test/resources/com/yourapp/features/featurefile.feature. Then the attribute would be @Feature(value="com/yourapp/features/featurefile.feature")