# gradle cucumber jvm exception: No features found at [classpath:]

Tags: cucumber, gradle, cucumber-jvm

I have already looked at the similar posts and followed the suggestions in there, still not able to execute any cucumber test using command: gradle test. It always returns the same error saying cannot find .feature files.

Similar posts:
1) [cucumber jvm CucumberException: No features found at []](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437715/cucumber-jvm-cucumberexception-no-features-found-at)
2) [Gradle doesn't pick up Cucumber-jvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330508/gradle-doesnt-pick-up-cucumber-jvm?rq=1)
3) [How do I set the path to my Cucumber features using cucumber-junit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663117/how-do-i-set-the-path-to-my-cucumber-features-using-cucumber-junit?rq=1)
4) [Specify the feature file location in cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861060/specify-the-feature-file-location-in-cucumber?rq=1)

Here is my gradle build script:

```
sourceSets {
        main {          
            java.srcDir 'src/jjrom'
        }
        test {
            java.srcDir 'src/test/java'
            resources.srcDir 'src/test/resources'      
        }
    }

dependencies {
 testCompile : "junit:junit:4.11"
 testCompile : "info.cukes:cucumber-core:1.1.5"
 testCompile : "info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.1.5"
 testCompile : "info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.1.5"
 testCompile : "info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.1.5"
 testCompile : "org.picocontainer:picocontainer:2.14.3"

 testCompile : "info.cukes:gherkin:2.9.3"
 testCompile : "info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.3"
 testCompile : "info.cukes:cucumber-spring:1.1.5"
 testCompile : "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3"
}
```

Now, my folder structure is as follows:

```
src/test/
    java/
        com/mypackage/
            Sample.java
    resources
        com/mypackage/
            test.feature
```

My Sample.java class looks like this:

```
package test.java.com.mypackage;

import cucumber.api.junit.*;
import org.junit.runner.*;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class Sample_cucumber_test {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you get rid of the ':' between configuration an dependency notation in your dependency section and try again? I mean instead of

```
dependencies {
 testCompile : "junit:junit:4.11"
 testCompile : "info.cukes:cucumber-core:1.1.5"
 testCompile : "info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.1.5"
 testCompile : "info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.1.5"
 testCompile : "info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.1.5"
 testCompile : "org.picocontainer:picocontainer:2.14.3"

 testCompile : "info.cukes:gherkin:2.9.3"
 testCompile : "info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.3"
 testCompile : "info.cukes:cucumber-spring:1.1.5"
 testCompile : "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3"
}
```

do

```
dependencies {
 testCompile "junit:junit:4.11"
 testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-core:1.1.5"
 testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.1.5"
 testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.1.5"
 testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.1.5"
 testCompile "org.picocontainer:picocontainer:2.14.3"

 testCompile "info.cukes:gherkin:2.9.3"
 testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.3"
 testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-spring:1.1.5"
 testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3"
}
```

Comment: In the project I'm maintaining a dependencies.gradle file which has a ext.libraries = {
    cucumber_core:"info.cukes:cucumber-core:1.1.5",
    cucumber_picocontainer:"info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.1.5",
    .... many more..
}
So the issue is not with the gradle syntax but with the cucumber test not being able to locate the .feature file.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce it, can you create a small reproducable example and make it available somewhere (e.g. github /bitbucket)? thank you very much.